# How to detect relationships using Microsoft Cognitive services?

Tags: relation, azure-cognitive-services, information-extraction, azure-language-understanding

Microsoft Cognitive Services offers a wide variety of capabilities to extract information from natural language. However I am not able to find how to use them in order to detect "relationships" where e.g. two (or more) specific "entities" are involved.

For example, detecting company acquisitions / merging.
These could be expressed in News articles as
"Company 1" has announced to acquire "Company2".

Certainly, there are several approaches to address that need, some that include entity detection first (e.g. Company1 and Company2 being companies) and then the relation (e.g. acquire ...).

Other approaches involve identifying first the "action" ( acquire ) and then through grammatical analysis find which is the "actor" and which the "object" of the action.

Machine learning approaches for semantic relation extraction has also been developed, in order to avoid humans to craft formal relation rules.

I would like to know if  / how this use case can be performed with the Microsoft Cognitive Services.

Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

Depends on tech used to examine response from the API [https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ps6ss.png)

I use JQuery to parse the json response (webclient in asp.net code behind) from Luis/Cognitive Services API (I am not using the Bot Framework). I have a rules engine that I can configure for clients and save it, so that when the page loads, they fire functions based on the parsed json response. The rules engine includes various condition functions like contains, begins with, is, etc so I can test the users query for specific entities or virtually anything in the users query. It really comes down to a && or || javascript functions...

For example if **intent=product** in the json response, I then show a shopping cart widget. Or if  **entity=coffee black** OR **entity=double double** then it triggers a widget to inject into the chat window (SHOW Shopping Cart). In short you either handle the AND/OR via the Bot Framework or via your tech of choice.

[image]